# How do I unhighlight an accessory in a UITableView after the row is deselected?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a custom accessory button. When the table cell is selected, the accessory button is placed in a highlighted state. Fine, that's a good thing. When another cell is selected, causing the first to deselect, the accessory button is not changed back to an unhighlighted state.

Here's a screen shot showing a cell (Rose) that is no longer selected, but still has the accessory button selected.

[image]

I've tried the solution suggested here. [AccessoryDetailDisclosureButton not deselecting after I call deselectRowAtIndexPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204835/accessorydetaildisclosurebutton-not-deselecting-after-i-call-deselectrowatindexp) It doesn't work. I reloaded every cell in the table, and it still does not place the accessory button in an unhighlighted state.

I've tried explicitly unhighlighting the button in the cell, both in the selector for the newly selected button and in the `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:` method. No joy.

Here's the code that creates the button:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
...
    UIButton *folderButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
    folderButton.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 33.0, 33.0);
    [folderButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"open_document.png"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [folderButton addTarget: self action: @selector(documentButtonAction:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [folderButton setTag: [program tag]];
    cell.accessoryView = folderButton;

...
}
```

The only solution I've found so far is to set the highlighted button image to the unhighlighted image, but that' pretty awful, too, since the button doesn't highlight when tapped.

How do I unhighlight the accessory button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...

```
[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathToDeselect]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

where `indexPathToDeselect` is the index path of the row that was previously highlighted. This will force that row to be redrawn.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, I did try this method. It did not work.

Comment: Oddly enough, though, I tried reloading the entire table rather than the row, and that _did_ work. Weird.


    [self.programTableView reloadData];

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the delegate methods `tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:`
and deselect your custom accessoryView there.

Comment: See above. I did try this; it did not work. There must be something else odd in the table. In any case, when I reloaded the _entire_ table, rather than just the rows, it worked.